# Basic C header file syntax

Tags: c, header-files

I am looking at a math.h header included in my IDE.  I am seeing the following code that is syntax I don't understand.  This is basic stuff but can someone explain to me how this works?

```
#define isgreater(x,y) \
          (__extension__ ({__typeof__(x) __x = (x); __typeof__(y) __y = (y); \
                           !isunordered(__x,__y) && (__x > __y);}))
```

So for example what does it do when you start something with double underscore  eg: `__typeof`
Is that to allow for undefined sizes?  so this macro can take values of different sizes?

Is the slash just to span line breaks in the source?

what does `__extension__` do?

thanks

Answer (score 8):

You are seeing the use of a few compiler extensions:

- `__typeof__` is a GCC extension that lets you get the type of the variable (and use it in a variable declaration); it is there so that the macro can handle whatever type `x` and `y` are.
- The second GCC extension turns `({ ... })` into an expression *that evaluates to the value of the last statement inside it*; this lets you declare variables inside this block, which is for the purpose of avoiding evaluating the two operands `x` and `y` twice. The results of `x` and `y` (which could be something like `i++` which you don't want to evaluate twice) are stored in two temporary variables `__x` and `__y` and then those two temporary variables are used instead of `x` and `y` to avoid double evaluation.
- `__extension__` is an extension that suppresses the warning you'd otherwise get about using the above extension.

And yes, the `\` just makes the definition of the macro span multiple lines (`\` joins lines together and is done very early in the compilation process, even before the macros and preprocessor definitions get looked at).

The whole point of this rigmarole is to avoid evaluating `x` and `y` twice. If you did

```
bool g = isgreater(x++, y++);
```

And you didn't use that trick, you'd get

```
bool g = !isunordered(x++, y++) && (x++ > y++);
```

Which would cause `x` and `y` to be incremented twice each instead of just once like you intended. Instead, with the trick, you get something like (using better names for the temporary variables)

```
int tmpx = x++;
int tmpy = y++;
bool g = !isunordered(tmpx, tmpy) && (tmpx > tmpy);
```

(if `x` and `y` are integers) which is correct and avoids double incrementation. This goes for other things as well, such as function calls:

```
isgreater(launch_missiles(3), launch_missiles(4));
```

Without the trick, you'd end up launching 14 missiles instead of 7, which would be catastrophic.

Comment: `&&` introduces a sequence point so the behavior isn't undefined, but the larger point is valid; you don't want to evaluate `x++` and `y++` more than once.

Comment: @JohnBode ah you're right, I forgot that `&&` introduced a sequence point. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This reformatting of the definition may help you

```
#define isgreater(x,y)                        \
(                                             \
  __extension__ (                             \
    {                                         \
      __typeof__(x) __x = (x);                \
      __typeof__(y) __y = (y);                \
      !isunordered(__x,__y) && (__x > __y);   \
    }                                         \
  )                                           \
)
```

`__extension__` marks code which uses gcc extensions to standard ANSI C. The extension in this case is the `__typeof__` operator which provides the type of a variable at compile time, and it is used to declare `__x` and `__y` with the same types as `x` and `y`. It then goes ahead and checks that the pair of values are both *ordered* (`isunordered` is a Math library function) and `__x` is greater than `__y`.

Comment: yea that makes more sense...after I read the first response I figured this out and now I can see the formating but this is great.  Thanks

Comment: so what does it mean to have double underscore on both sides of something like __typeof__?

Comment: @user1054210 They just named it something that wouldn't conflict with other names. They could have named it `rumpletstiltskin` if they wanted; `__typeof__` is just what they chose. They use that naming convention for extensions usually.

Comment: @user1054210 also, C programmers (as users of the compiler) are not allowed to use names that start with two underscores because they're reserved for compiler writers, so they knew that `__typeof__` would not be taken.